# Loopback: not receiving the id of inserted object with upsert

Tags: mysql, node.js, strongloop, upsert, loopback

I have this upsert in a loopback code;

it works perfectly on updating, but when inserting the new address it return the 0 I'm passing it, not the new adress' id that is created in the db.

Here's the code of my Upsert:

```
promise.then(function(data) {
      var address = new app.models.Address();
      if(data[0].addressId) {
        address.addressId = data[0].addressId; //id
      } else {
        address.addressId = 0;
      }
      address.street = dataUpdate.address.street;
      address.zipCode = dataUpdate.address.zipCode;
      address.city = dataUpdate.address.city;
      address.province = dataUpdate.address.province;
      address.country = dataUpdate.address.country;
      address.latitude = dataUpdate.address.latitude;
      address.longitude = dataUpdate.address.longitude;

      app.models.Address.upsert(address, function (err, objAddress) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cb(null, objAddress);
      });
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read the Loopback blog for Promises? Looks like the code might be slightly different. https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

Comment: Hi, I've read through but apparently there is no problem, I receive data correctly from the promise, is at doing upsert that I'm not receiving the new one.

Comment: Wow! 4 years and still no answer! No wonder no one uses loopback.